# Prooving independence of events

Tags: probability, statistics, independence

Let $A, B$ and $C$ be independent events. Let $D$ be any event in the $\sigma$-field generated by $\{B,C\}$. Show that $A$ and $D$ are independent.

I know the definition of  independence and all but I really don't know where to even start. Could someone give a guidance on where to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sigma algebra is: $\begin{align}\sigma \{B, C\} = & \{\varnothing, B, B^\complement, C, C^\complement, B\cap C, B\cap C^\complement, B^\complement\cap C, B^\complement\cap C^\complement, B\cup C, B\cup C^\complement, B^\complement\cup C, B^\complement\cup C^\complement, \Omega\}
\\ = & \{B^x\cap C^y: B^x \in \{B, \Omega\setminus B, \Omega\}, C^y \in \{C, \Omega\setminus C, \Omega\}\} \cup \{\Omega\setminus(B^x\cap C^y): B^x \in \{B, \Omega\setminus B, \Omega\}, C^y \in \{C, \Omega\setminus C, \Omega\}\} \end{align}$

For all $B^x, C^y$, as above, show that :

- $\mathsf P(A\cap (B^x\cap C^y))=\mathsf P(A) \mathsf P(B^x\cap C^y)$

Answer (score 0):

By definition of independence of $A$ and $B$ and $C$:

P(A and B) = P(A) $\cdot$ P(B)
P(A and C) = P(A) $\cdot$ P(C)

Therefore, you can show the following by induction on $n$:

If $D$ is the event consisting of $n$ copies of $B$ or $C$, then

P(A and D) = P(A) $\cdot$ P(D)

Comment: May I ask what you mean by induction on n?

Comment: If $D=B^x\cap C^y$, then $n = x+y$.  So for $n=1$, you have to prove the statement when $D=B$ or $D=C$; for $n=2$, it's $D = B\cap C$ or $B^2$ or $C^2$, etc.  To prove for all lengths of $D$, you have to use induction.  Assume the statement holds when length of $D$ is $n-1$, and show that the statement holds when the length of $D$ is $n$.